# How to add MahApps.Metro Context Menu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, mahapps.metro

I fount [this](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ContextMenu.xaml) `Context Menu` style that i want to add to my application.
I put it In `Windows.Resources` ad add the style (Style="{StaticResource MetroContextMenu}") into my `ContextMenu` - nothing happen and my `ContextMenu`
is still the same so i try to put it inside `App.XAML` ans still my `ContextMenu` have the old style.
Am i missing something ?

**Update**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"        
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="670"
        Width="1024"
        GlowBrush="Black"
        ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
        TitleCaps="False"
        TitleForeground="White"
        EnableDWMDropShadow="True">
```

My `context menu`:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="lvFileMenu" Style="{StaticResource MetroContextMenu}">
                    <MenuItem Name="openCaptureMenuItem" Header="Open file" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/open.ico"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [quick  start for MahApps](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html)?

make sure you have `Controls:MetroWindow` instead of `Window` tag

Comment: Yes i have this tag and form style is metro